Mongodb is not persisting data. I am loosing the database after some hours of insertion
Here is the code of my docker-compose file. I have issue with data persistence.  Why it is getting deleted after some hours of insertion.
services:
     mongodb:
      image: mongo:latest
      container_name: afilal-mongodb
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
       - "27017:27017"
      volumes:
       - afilal_mongo_data:/data/db
     backend:
      build: ./backend
      ports:
       - "5000:5000"
      environment:
       - NODE_ENV=production
       - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/afilaldb
      depends_on:
       - mongodb
    
     frontend:
      build: ./frontend
      ports:
       - "80:80"
    
    volumes:
     afilal_mongo_data:
      external: false


The volume mounted on /data/db matches what's described in the Docker Hub mongo image page.  Can you say anything more about what's inserting data, what data you're no longer seeing, or provide any details beyond this Compose file?

Actually, the mongodb database is getting deleted. Whole db is gone after some hours of insertion.
